# Packaging a single jar including few netty jar files?

Tags: netty

I am building a protocol stack using some of the netty java libraries version 4.x and will distribute the stack commercially. I want to distribute it as a single jar with all the netty dependencies. Is it allowed?

Comment: The important part of distributing Netty is that you follow the [licence](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/LICENSE.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally yes as Netty uses Apache License 2.0 . That said you need to give some attribution like stated here:

https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0